# Paperclip S3 uploads with S3 credentials stored in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've got a Site model which allows for a background_image upload to S3 via Paperclip. Where it gets weird is that each Site has it's own S3 credentials store in it's model. My question is this, how can I reference the site's own attributes when uploading via Paperclip?

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :background_image, 
                  :s3_access_key_id,
                  :s3_secret_access_key,
                  :s3_username

  has_attached_file :background_image,
                    storage: :s3,
                    s3_credentials: {
                      access_key_id: @s3_access_key_id.to_s,
                      secret_access_key: @s3_secret_access_key.to_s
                    },
                    bucket: "my-app",
                    s3_permissions: "public-read",
                    path: "/home/#{@s3_username}/background_images/:id/:filename"
end
```

Unfortunately with this setup I just get `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records`. I assume it's just getting blank values because it works fine when I hard-code the values from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that `has_attached_file` is a being called on the `Site` *class* when `site.rb` is first read, not on the site instance. Fortunately, paperclip supports dynamic configuration in several places, wherein you can retrieve the `Site` *instance* at runtime. Try this instead:

```
has_attached_file :background_image,
  s3_credentials: lambda { |attachment| attachment.instance.s3_keys },
  path: lambda { |attachment| "/home/#{attachment.instance.s3_username}/background_images/:id/filename" }


def s3_keys
  {
    access_key_id: self.s3_access_key_id.to_s,
    secret_access_key: self.s3_secret_access_key.to_s
  }
end
```

Those lambdas will get evaluated at runtime, with the `Paperclip::Attachment` object passed in as a param. You can retrieve the `Site` instance with `Paperclip::Attachment#instance`. So then you can call methods on the instance to get its specific keys.

You can also use a more specific/advanced trick for getting the `s3_username` into the path. You can just teach paperclip more path name interpolations. Like you could add a file at `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` with:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :s3_username do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.s3_username
end
```

and then your `Site` model could look like

```
has_attached_file :background_image,
  s3_credentials: lambda { |attachment| attachment.instance.s3_keys },
  path: "/home/:s3_username/background_images/:id/:filename"


def s3_keys
  {
    access_key_id: self.s3_access_key_id.to_s,
    secret_access_key: self.s3_secret_access_key.to_s
  }
end
```